# Mock HTML element in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

```
export function tryAddELement(){
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = 'sampleHref';
}
```

Im trying to write a Jest test for this, but I am stuck on creating the mock HTML element.

```
  it('test tryAddElement', () => {
    // const elementMock; // Stuck here
    // const createElementMock = jest.spyOn(document, "createElement").mockReturnValue(elementMock);

    tryAddELement();
  });
```

How do we mock a HMTL element in Jest?

Comment: How exactly are you stuck? You just created an element above in the `tryAddELement` function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
it('test tryAddElement', () => {
    tryAddELement();

    const expectedElement = document.getElementsByTagName("a[href='sampleHref']");

    expect(expectedElement).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: This test always passes, for me